# googlePlaces string problem iphone

Tags: iphone

1. i want to put name having spaces in googlePlaces query sting. my string is:

   googleUrl=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%f,%f&radius=500&name=the burber shop&sensor=false&key=mykey",ab,bb];

Please note

```
"&name=the burber shop"
```

in above string.
If i put &name=asda it works but because the burber shop has space in it, it does not work. Please suggest.

2
   i want to get full address of all shops. how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the URL.

http://blog.evandavey.com/2009/01/how-to-url-encode-nsstring-in-objective-c.html

Comment: Thanku it works. but how can we show full address. like in my output it shows street name. but i want to show office no. as well. like 34 buisness park etc